# How do I query in kibana with "average time_taken" field from log IIS based on URL

Tags: iis, filter, kibana

I'm using ELK for my IIS webserver's log analysis. Recently the website is quite slow I'm trying to filter which URL has slowest average `time_taken`.
I'm filtering like the picture below:

[image]

but I don't know how to filter more specifically, such as which URL has average time_taken slower then 3 seconds, which I really need to know indeed

Do you have any experience like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After asking some of my mentor, I've finally find out how to filter with the aggregation

checkout the picture below:

[aggregation filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oA2em.jpg)